# Crafter CMS - Can the date format be set to a standard ISO format?

Tags: crafter-cms

I'm using the REST api with Crafter CMS, and the dates are formatted in a US locale specific format like:
 m/d/y h:m:s

This is really surprising and I hope there is a good reason for it, but more importantly, can I change it globally so it uses a standard ISO format that is locale independent? Is it using the default Java locale, the system locale, or is it just hardwired that way?
Right now I am parsing it and reformatting it, but I would rather not have to do that everywhere a date is used, and I'm afraid if it runs on another machine, the format might change to whatever the locale is there which would break everything.

Comment: Can you add one or two example APIs that are doing that?

Comment: Use the Headless_blog blueprint, and reference this URL http://localhost:8080/api/1/post/list.json and the dates look like **5/11/2017 16:25:0**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crafter CMS does not depend on the system locale to format dates, it will always use the same format in the UTC timezone. Currently the format is `MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss`

There is an open ticket to change it to ISO: https://github.com/craftercms/craftercms/issues/1415

Meanwhile, you can update the Groovy REST scripts in the Headless Blueprint to do the conversion for you so you don't have to do it in your application.